# SUM of column that has been GROUPED BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT mgap_growth 
FROM mgap_orders 
WHERE account_manager_id = '159795' 
GROUP BY mgap_ska_report_category
```

mgap_growth is a column with identical amounts that differ only per mgap_ska_report_category, which is the reason for the grouping. Now hat I have normalized the individual amounts per category, how can I use SUM to tally their total?

Here is a screenshot of the data:

[image]

I only need the SUM of the growth amounts per category, not of all of the mgap_growth records, but Im unsure as to how to SUM after the grouping.

Thanks!

**EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL QUERY:**

Let me throw another issue into the mix: we know I need to SUM only once per category, but what if I needed to GROUP BY CUSTOMER? I just found out that there are multiple customers in the data, each is duplicated per growth record, but differ by category. I really need to use two groupings, one for category to single out and SUM the growth amount and then another the single out the customer.

Here is an image describing the data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to sum the results from the subquery.

```
SELECT SUM(mgap_growth) AS total_mgap_growth
FROM (SELECT mgap_growth 
      from mgap_orders 
      WHERE account_manager_id = '159795' 
      GROUP BY mgap_ska_report_category) AS x
```

Comment: I think you may have mis-read?  I think the OP wants a sum per grouped category.  If the OP wants a overall sum, there's no point in the subquery with the group by.

Comment: @Andrew . . . I think Barmar understood the question correctly.

Comment: @Barmar - That did it - Thanks - If I wanted add an additional column to the query where would I add it? Im getting an undefined index when I try and add another column to the second SELECT like this: FROM (SELECT mgap_growth, name from mgap_orders...I dont need to SUM the additional column, its just for labeling purposes.

Comment: You need to add it to both the subquery and the outer query. But What's the point of adding the name? You're summing across all names, so there's no single name for the main query.

Answer (score 0):

This should should show the total growth per category for that particular account manager:

```
SELECT sum(mgap_growth) AS Growth, mgap_ska_report_category as Category 
FROM mgap_orders
WHERE account_manager_id = '159795' 
GROUP BY mgap_ska_report_category
```

Rather than thinking of doing the SUM *after* the grouping, you can do the two together in the one statement.  You were 99% of the way there with what you had already.

---

To answer your additional question in the comment, you can add another column to group by.  The order that you list them in the group by section is the important part.  The overall grouping comes first.  So assuming 'Customer' is the customer column name you would do this:

```
SELECT mgap_ska_report_category as Category, Customer, sum(mgap_growth) AS Growth
FROM mgap_orders
WHERE account_manager_id = '159795' 
GROUP BY mgap_ska_report_category, customer
WITH ROLLUP
```

Note that changing the SELECT columns in the top line was just for aesthetics, you can put them in any order and will get the same data, but this will be the easiest to read.

This shows the growth per customer by category for that particular account manager.

---

Edited again to add WITH ROLLUP.  This will give you the totals per category as well.  Try it with and without the WITH ROLLUP to see the how it changes things.

Comment: That makes sense..let me throw another issue into the mix: we know I need to SUM only once per category, but what if I needed to GROUP BY CUSTOMER? I just found out that there are multiple customers in the data, each is duplicated per growth record, but differ by category. I really need to use two groupings, one for category to single out and SUM the growth amount and then another the single out the customer.I have added a image to my code above to better explain.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the additional question.  You could also add an additional where clause to the original solution to limit by customer.  WHERE account_manager_id = '159795' and Customer = 'X'